# SwiftUI: .navigationTitle showing on Preview, but not on Simulator

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

As the title says: the nav title shows on the previews (for all pages I've tried it on), but when I open up the simulator, it is not there. I tried it both with navtitle and also with the toolbar with toolbar items. The same result: OK in Preview, not showing on Simulator.
Thanks.

Here is an ex of my code (knowing that @main is wrapped in NavigationStack itself

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    
    
    init() { FirebaseApp.configure() }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                MainView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

, so no need for it here):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var VM: VM
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            BgViewTurned()
            
            VStack {
                Text("example text")
                
                Button {
                    // do something 

                } label: {
                    Text("a text")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Profile")
            

          
            
            
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
        ProfileView()
            .environmentObject(VM())
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting `.navigationTitle("Profile")` on the `ZStack` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. But nothing changed. Shows in preview, not on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like below-

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
                ProfileView() 
        }
    }
}
```

And,

```swift
var body: some View {

 NavigationView{
                ZStack{
                          BgViewTurned()
                           
                           VStack {
                               Text("example text")
                               Button {

                               } label: {
                                   Text("a text")
                               }
                               .padding()
                           }
                       }
                .navigationTitle("Profile")

                   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this worked, but it messes up other parts of my code that work great for what I have build, mainly envobjects. But this solutions works. PS: I did vote for it, but it didn't take the vote, because I need 15 reputation. Sorry.

Comment: @redwolfG No worries, do it next time if you appreciate the answer